# How to attach TapTargetView to a specific view in a fragment in tab layout

Tags: android, android-fragments

Here is my code and what i have tried. the problem in my code is that  I have three tabs and my TapTarget View on 2nd, but TapTargetView is inflated as soon as when 1st fragment comes in the View.

this is my main Activity

```
public class HomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

TabLayoutAdapter adapter;
private TabLayout tabLayout;
private int[] tabIcons = {
        R.drawable.ic_tab_new,
        R.drawable.ic_random,
        R.drawable.ic_favorite
};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_category);
    ViewPager viewPager = findViewById(R.id.viewpager);

    // setting up the adapter, adapter tells which fragment to load
    adapter = new TabLayoutAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());// call of consturctor
    setupViewPager(viewPager);
    tabLayout = findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
    setupTabIcons();


    tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            int tabIconColor = ContextCompat.getColor(getBaseContext(), R.color.selectedTabColor); // change color of selected tab
            tab.getIcon().setColorFilter(tabIconColor, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);




        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            int tabIconColor = ContextCompat.getColor(getBaseContext(), R.color.tabUnselectedColor);
            tab.getIcon().setColorFilter(tabIconColor, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }
    });
}
```

fragment in which i have to inflate the TapTargetView

```
  public class CategoryFragment extends Fragment {

private List<String> lastSearches;
private MaterialSearchBar searchBar;
private List<Category> categoryList;
private ProgressBar progressBar;
private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private CategoriesAdapter adapter, duplicateAdapter;
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_category, container, false);
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    progressBar = view.findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
    progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(), 2));
    categoryList = new ArrayList<>();
    adapter = new CategoriesAdapter(getActivity(), categoryList);
    duplicateAdapter = new CategoriesAdapter(getActivity(), categoryList);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);


    searchBar = view.findViewById(R.id.searchBar);
    searchBar.setHint("Luffy...");


    TapTargetView.showFor(getActivity(),                 // `this` is an Activity
TapTarget.forView(searchbar, "This is a target", "We have the best targets, believe me")
    // All options below are optional
    .outerCircleColor(R.color.red)      // Specify a color for the outer circle
.outerCircleAlpha(0.96f)            // Specify the alpha amount for the outer circle
    .targetCircleColor(R.color.white)   // Specify a color for the target circle
    .titleTextSize(20)                  // Specify the size (in sp) of the title text
    .titleTextColor(R.color.white)      // Specify the color of the title text
    .descriptionTextSize(10)            // Specify the size (in sp) of the description text
    .descriptionTextColor(R.color.red)  // Specify the color of the description text
    .textColor(R.color.blue)            // Specify a color for both the title and description text
    .textTypeface(Typeface.SANS_SERIF)  // Specify a typeface for the text
    .dimColor(R.color.black)            // If set, will dim behind the view with 30% opacity of the given color
    .drawShadow(true)                   // Whether to draw a drop shadow or not
    .cancelable(false)                  // Whether tapping outside the outer circle dismisses the view
    .tintTarget(true)                   // Whether to tint the target view's color
    .transparentTarget(false)           // Specify whether the target is transparent (displays the content underneath)
    .icon(Drawable)                     // Specify a custom drawable to draw as the target
    .targetRadius(60),                  // Specify the target radius (in dp)
new TapTargetView.Listener() {          // The listener can listen for regular clicks, long clicks or cancels
    @Override
    public void onTargetClick(TapTargetView view) {
        super.onTargetClick(view);      // This call is optional
        doSomething();
    }
});

    }
}
```

i have also tried the TapTargetView to in the activity by checking which tabs is currently open but that crashes the app saying Null Value of View is given.

Can anyone tell me what i have been doing wrong, and how to fix this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that the problem was caused because viewpager inflates the next fragment in the view, so to execute a specific line of only when a specific fragment is opened below is the code.

```
    @Override
public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
    super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
    if (isVisibleToUser) {
        //Write down your refresh code here, it will call every time user come to this fragment.
        //OR code that has to be executed only when this fragment of opened

    }
}
```

below is the complete code solution for the above problem.....

```
@Override
public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
    super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
    if (isVisibleToUser) {
        //Write down your refresh code here, it will call every time user come to this fragment.



        TapTargetView.showFor(getActivity(),                 // `this` is an Activity
                TapTarget.forView(searchbar, "This is a target", "We have the best targets, believe me")
                        // All options below are optional
                        .outerCircleColor(R.color.red)      // Specify a color for the outer circle
                        .outerCircleAlpha(0.96f)            // Specify the alpha amount for the outer circle
                        .targetCircleColor(R.color.white)   // Specify a color for the target circle
                        .titleTextSize(20)                  // Specify the size (in sp) of the title text
                        .titleTextColor(R.color.white)      // Specify the color of the title text
                        .descriptionTextSize(10)            // Specify the size (in sp) of the description text
                        .descriptionTextColor(R.color.red)  // Specify the color of the description text
                        .textColor(R.color.blue)            // Specify a color for both the title and description text
                        .textTypeface(Typeface.SANS_SERIF)  // Specify a typeface for the text
                        .dimColor(R.color.black)            // If set, will dim behind the view with 30% opacity of the given color
                        .drawShadow(true)                   // Whether to draw a drop shadow or not
                        .cancelable(false)                  // Whether tapping outside the outer circle dismisses the view
                        .tintTarget(true)                   // Whether to tint the target view's color
                        .transparentTarget(false)           // Specify whether the target is transparent (displays the content underneath)
                        .icon(Drawable)                     // Specify a custom drawable to draw as the target
                        .targetRadius(60),                  // Specify the target radius (in dp)
                new TapTargetView.Listener() {          // The listener can listen for regular clicks, long clicks or cancels
                    @Override
                    public void onTargetClick(TapTargetView view) {
                        super.onTargetClick(view);      // This call is optional
                        doSomething();
                    }
                });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to defer showing the TapTargetView to when the layout/view is inflated, you can use `View.post(Runnable)` on the view that you are trying to wait on. You can also use `View.postDelayed(Runnable, delay)` and delay your code a bit after inflation. In these cases you can make sure that your view is inflated because `post` is not called before the inflation and it's layout is complete.

Comment: not working, if i wait for few seconds the same thing happens i am on first page and my View is on 2nd page, but it still inflates even though we are currently on 1st page

Comment: i read somewhere that viewpager loads other pages for faster access, that is causing  the problem